# Vaadin Content Management System

Tags: java, content-management-system, liferay, vaadin7

I want to ask if in Vaadin is something similar to Liferay web content management?

Is there a way to dynamically change content of a web page/application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. Vaadin is a UI framework that can easily be used to build a CMS system, but contains no built in CMS module. E.g. Magnolia, popular CMS platform, has its administration features built using Vaadin.

Among Liferay users it is common to use Liferays built in CMS module for static content and then build more dynamic application like parts using Vaadin (portlets). This is actually how vaadin.com itself is run.